# Addition of forces in dielectric material

Tags: forces, electrostatics, dielectric

In [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/ed077p1520) (page 2 of document) it is said that:

> Because this calculated force was comparable to the gravitational
>   force, they assumed that the same would be true for the forces on a
>   droplet; that is, that the total electrical force on a droplet would
>   be the sum of the forces on individual free molecules, scaling in the
>   same way as the gravitational force. This ignores the fact that owing
>   to the large dielectric constant of water, the electrical force on
>   molecules in the interior of the droplet is reduced by a factor of ca.
>   80

In context, they seem to try to say that the net force of a drop of water in a non-uniform electric field isn't just the sum of the forces that each molecule would feel in isolation (so not counting *internal* forces).

However, I think that all forces that obey [Newton's third law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_third_law), have the property that the net force in a system of interacting particles is equal to the sum of only the *external* forces acting on the particles in the system. I also think that dipole-dipole forces obey Newton's third law. So is what they assert here wrong?

Comment: No, the dipoles near the center of a (large enough) droplet are screened by the closer dipoles. The outer ones align to be happy in the external field, which reduces the field further inside.

Comment: Well, I know the field in the middle is less, but does that reduce the total force? Consider for example the setup    (-)___(-)___(+)......(-) . Where the _ are fixed bars and .. is empty space. The negative charge in the middle sees a smaller E field than if the other two charges weren't there, but to calculate the total force you still calculate its contribution by multiplying its charge by the electric field due to the charge on the far right, which is the E field that it would feel if the other two charges weren't there.